# Is there a national movement for a plural executive in the federal government?

Tags: united-states, executive

In the United States, there has been a long standing movement for the [unitary power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_executive_theory) of the executive branch. That is, there is a well known movement that purports:

> a "hierarchical, unified executive department under the direct control
>   of the President."

Out of curiosity, I was wondering if there has been a long standing movement of comparable notoriety for the opposite type of executive.  That is: **Is there a movement for multiple elected members of the executive branch at the federal level?** i.e., something like the state governments of [Texas](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/odessa-texasgovernment/chapter/plural-executive/) or [Massachusetts](https://budget.digital.mass.gov/bb/h1/fy10h1/prnt10/exec10/pbuddevstructure.htm).

Comment: Depending on the definition of "widely known", to ask the question is to answer it.

Comment: Are you talking about something like electing the equivalent of cabinet positions (your MA example would include the Secretary of State, Attorney General, etc.) separately from the President? Or some sort of multi-person executive leader position, like the Roman consul?

Comment: By widely known I mean of comparable  notoriety to the unitary executive movement.  In addition, when I mean "Plural Executive", I mean the examples cited (i.e., electing your own Attorney General etc.)